# Floating Action Menu like Google Hangout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, action-menu

I am trying to make a FLoating Action Menu similar to Google Hangout. I have tried 
https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton
But still I am not able to achieve that. I want the Floating action menu as described in the image.

[image]

When I will click on filter button, the button should appear and also the background should be faded. and if we click anywhere else, the menu should close. Please help. I have trying to design the same from past 2 weeks.

Comment: I have also used https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidFloatingActionButton and https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button to build the same..

Comment: I have created this. https://i.imgsafe.org/2dbe586.png. I want to replace the cross icon with the filter icon.

Comment: I have created this using github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button library and it clearly showing that we dont have the option to change the icon. So please help.

Comment: Try using the Floating Action Button as part of the Design support library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the android design support floating action button. You can design the 3 floating action buttons and accordingly assign the respective images to it and also give animations to achieve the floating action menu like hangout

Comment: can you please suggest me some code?

Comment: Ya i can mail me you sample project where i had tried that animation of floating action menu without any libraries, you can try that. How can I send you the source code?

Comment: Just check this link i had tried a sample project on social media integration i had used the floating menu animation in it - https://github.com/nairpooja7/SocialMediaIntegrationExample

Comment: Will mail you the project shortly according to the screenshot you have specified

Comment: I have mailed you the code.. i have used the clans library but according to how you wanted i changed the icons and color.. just execute the project first which i mailed you.

Comment: @PoojaNair can you please mail me the same code @ f.shaikh1993@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what you want. See [this github project](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton).

Yes, Its very easy to integrate and I'm quoting the basic integration part from there.

Add this in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.3'
}
```

In your layout add this `FloatingActionMenu`

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/menu_yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/jump_from_down"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/jump_to_down"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#444"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#FFB805"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#F2AB00"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#D99200">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        fab:fab_label="Menu item 1"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        fab:fab_label="Menu item 2"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        fab:fab_label="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        style="@style/MenuButtonsStyle" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

You can have the attributes of `FloatingActionMenu` customized. See the documentation in detail.

**Update**

To change the menu labels you can have your custom style like this in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MenuLabelsStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

For more information about changing the `fab_label` colour, see [this issue](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues/142).

Comment: I have tried this library. but when we implement this library, we are not able to change the text color and background color of the labels.

Comment: You're referring to the `fab_label` right? See the updated answer

Comment: yes, the background and text color of that label.

Comment: See the updated answer. You can easily customize that too.

Comment: Also I need to fade the background and if the user touches any area, then the menu should close.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this can help you.
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#

Maybe if this dont help you, you can have a look to this video (Its not mine)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5AZvqJ1YFg

Comment: Sorry, this didnt work for me... as the buttons are in in a circle and they dont have label. I need exactly as per the image. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry i dont know a lot more than this, good luck finding the answer :)